# Removing entire barline in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond, engraving

How can I remove the entirety of the barlines (including that between the staves) from these examples using a `\with`-based solution?

I continue trying the solutions [shown in the documentation](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/visibility-of-objects), but with no success. Note that the `\new StaffGroup` is necessary for my larger project, so this should only apply to this particular `PianoStaff`.

```
\version "2.20.0"

music = \relative c' {
  c1 c
}

<<
  \new StaffGroup
  \new PianoStaff \with {
    \omit Staff.BarLine
  }
  
  <<
    \new Staff \music
    \new Staff \music
  >>
>>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need `StaffGroup` and nothing else? Your problem is essentially in the fact that the `StaffGroup` adds barlines through all its systems. So I don't think your problem can be solved without touching the `StaffGroup`. I could perhaps give some recommendation if you described what the final product should look like.

Comment: @Ramillies I was afraid of this. I think the `StaffGroup` is the best environment, since I'm going to have multiple staves moving simultaneously. See https://music.stackexchange.com/q/124631/21766 for some context.

Comment: So you want all of the staves in your `StaffGroup` above and below this one to have connected barlines that would be interrupted in this `PianoStaff` only? Still not sure about what you want. If you don't want that, use `ChoirStaff`, which is just like `StaffGroup` but without the connected barlines. If you do want that, I guess it would be better to use no group at all for this and stick the braces on it ex post.

Comment: Ultimately it will be three staves where only the bottom staff has barlines. The `ChoirStaff` is a clever workaround. But does its barline properties revert to those of `StaffGroup` if the `ChoirStaff` is nested within a larger `StaffGroup`?

Comment: Are you sure you still want the time signature?

Comment: @Dekkadeci I don't, but that's easy enough to remove so I left it in for simplicity's sake.

Comment: @Richard – there are a few answers below, but (as you haven't voted for, or commented on any of them) it's unclear if they have helped or not.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace They have, and I apologize for waiting so long to respond! I may not accept anything yet as I'm still slowly working on my project, but my votes are indeed overdue, and thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3):

I went through the previous question you linked once more and hopefully I will be able to provide the solution you're looking for.

Simply put, replace all occurrences of `StaffGroup` in your score with `ChoirStaff` (don't forget to do it in `\context`s too). Then, do `\omit Staff.Barline` (that's the barlines inside the staves), as well as `\omit PianoStaff.SpanBar` (the parts between the staves).

So your example would be written thus:

```
music = \relative c' {
  c1 c
}

<<
  \new ChoirStaff
  \new PianoStaff \with {
    \omit Staff.BarLine
    \omit PianoStaff.SpanBar
  }
  <<
    \new Staff \music
    \new Staff \music
  >>
>>
```

[image]

`ChoirStaff` is just like `StaffGroup`, but without the connecting barlines. So the only thing supplying the barlines is the `PianoStaff`, from which we can easily remove them.

In your larger project, it would do something like this: (I used the code in the answer to your linked question and performed the aforementioned changes):

[image]

Would that be what you need, or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1):

As Ramillies said getting rid of the Spanbar can be done by simply using a ChoirStaff instead, with exactly that being the defining difference.

But if you want to do it you way the grob you’re looking for is `SpanBar`. But keep in mind that the `Span_bar_engraver` exists in both the PianoStaff and the StaffGroup, so you need to do it in both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
\version "2.20.0"

music = \relative c' {
  c1 c
}
leftHand = \relative c {
  \clef bass
  c1 c 
}

<<
  \new ChoirStaff << 
    \new PianoStaff \with {
      \omit BarLine
      \omit SpanBar
    }
    <<
      \new Staff \music
      \new Staff \leftHand
    >>
    \new Staff \music
  >>
>>
```